# How to set integer value ranging from 1000 to 9999 in Java?

Tags: java

This is my first time taking programming  class. This is also my first assignment, and I got stuck on how to set the input of number from users ranging from 1000 to 9999.

My assignment is create a code that ask user to enter four digit integer, then display those individual number 3 spaces from each other (hint: use division and remainder arithmetic).
I finally get it to print out each number 3 space away from each other.

The problem is when my teacher says that a four digit integer are ranging from 1000-9999. So when I try to put 0001, it print out: 
0   0   0   1

And if I put 12345, it print out:
12 3 4 5

Is there anyway to do it?

Thank you so much for help me out

I can post a picture yet because im new to this forum.

### anyway here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DigitsDemo
{
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );

    System.out.print ( "Enter four digit numbers: " );//prompt the user to enter numbers
    int n = input.nextInt();//read number entered by user

    // determine the 5 digits
    int Digit1 = n / 1000;
    int Digit2 = n % 1000 / 100;
    int Digit3 = n % 1000 % 100 / 10;
    int Digit4 = n % 1000 % 100 % 10 / 1;

    System.out.println ( "The four digits integers are:" );

    System.out.printf ( "%d   %d   %d   %d\n%s\n", Digit1, Digit2, Digit3, Digit4, "Written by blabla" );

}
```

### }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my teacher says that a four digit integer are ranging from 1000-9999
```

You need a while loop to check the data each time the user inputted it to the stream and check the integer if it is out of range using the `if statement` if it is then let the user to try again.

**sample:**

```
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );

    System.out.print ( "Enter four digit numbers: " );//prompt the user to enter numbers
    int n = input.nextInt();//read number entered by user

    // determine the 5 digits
    int Digit1;
    int Digit2;
    int Digit3;
    int Digit4;
    while(true)
    {
        if(n < 1000 || n > 9999)
        {
            System.out.println("Out of range, Sorry try again:");
            System.out.print ( "Enter four digit numbers: " );//prompt the user to enter numbers
            n = input.nextInt();//read number entered by user
        } else
        {
             Digit1 = n / 1000;
             Digit2 = n % 1000 / 100;
             Digit3 = n % 1000 % 100 / 10;
             Digit4 = n % 1000 % 100 % 10 / 1;
            break;
        }
    }


    System.out.println ( "The four digits integers are:" );

    System.out.printf ( "%d   %d   %d   %d\n%s\n", Digit1, Digit2, Digit3, Digit4, "Written by blabla" );

}
```

**result:**

```
Enter four digit numbers: 12345
Out of range, Sorry try again:
Enter four digit numbers: 1234
The four digits integers are:
1   2   3   4
Written by blabla
```

Comment: Roy, Thank you so much for your help. Im using book Deitel : Java How to program and so far we only cover chapter 1 and 2. Our teacher is not really a good source for help. Again, thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @andylie click the check button to mark this post as answered, You are welcome and happy coding/